# DataMapper: Create new record or update existing

Tags: ruby, datamapper

Does DataMapper provide a convenient way to create a new record when none exists or update an existing one? I couldn't find anything in the API documentation.

This is what I have at the moment which doesn't seem very elegant:

```
foo = Foo.get(id)
if foo.nil?
  foo = Foo.create(#attributes...)
else
  foo.update(#attributes...)
end
foo.save
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Foo.first_or_create(:id=>id).update(attributes)
```

or

```
(Foo.get(id) || Foo.new).update(attributes)
```

Comment: As of version 1.1.0 this will raise DataMapper::UpdateConflictError, Foo#update cannot be called on a new resource

Answer (score 1):

I just try

```
Foo.first_or_create(:id=>id).update(attributes)
```

but it gets wrong sometimes, so I find some tips from here:[DataMapper Docs](http://datamapper.org/docs/create_and_destroy.html)

Now I make my code works like:

```
Foo.first_or_create({:id=>id}, {:name => name}).update(:id => id, :name => name)
```

Hope it helps you.